# How to disprove that $∀_x (p(x)∨q(x))⊨∀_x p(x)∨∀_x q(x)$ with an interpretaion

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, formal-proofs

I am requested to prove or disprove that $\forall_x$ $(p(x)\lor q(x))$⊨$∀_x p(x)\lor ∀_xq(x)$

I have written the following interpretation bellow. However I have two questions concerning formalization...

1st.) I have written the function of the interpretation as $m(f)=${$0$,if $f=p$ or;$1$,if $f=q$}... However, this seems for me clearly wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to express such a function.

2nd.) It is the overall ending $∀_x(p(x)∨q(x))⊨∀_x p(x)∨∀_x q(x)$ correct? I mean, may I consider the symbol ⊨ as if it was $\rightarrow$? Because it seems to me that I have proved a statement by considering the antecedent true and consequent false of an implication, and so the overall implication is false.

#### Proof

This statement is false, to show this we choose the domain of interpretation to be {$0,1$}.
There are two predicate symbols that occur in their statements: $P$ and $Q$. Let's interpret $P(x)$ as the statement $x=0$, and $Q(x)$ as the statement $x=1$. So in symbols we have a function $m(f)=${$0$,if $f=p$ or;$1$,if $f=q$}.

Now we interpret the statement $∀x(P(x)∨Q(x))$ as the statement "For all $x ∈${$0,1$}, $x=0$ or x=1." This is clearly a true statement.

We also interpret the statement $∀xP(x)$ as "For all $x∈$ {$0,1$}, $x=0$." This is a false statement as $1∈{0,1}$ and $1≠0$.

We also interpret the statement $∀xQ(x)$ as "For all $x∈${$0,1$}, $x=1$." This is a false statement as $0 ∈${$0,1$} and $0≠1$.

Thus, we see that the statement $∀xP(x)∨∀xQ(x)$ is not true in this interpretation, since both $∀xP(x)$ and $∀xQ(x)$ are not true.

In this interpretation, $∀x(P(x)∨Q(x))$ is true, but $∀xP(x)∨∀xQ(x)$ is false. So it is not true that $∀_x(p(x)∨q(x))⊨∀_x p(x)∨∀_x q(x)$.

Comment: Another example: $p(x)$ is "$x$ is even" and $q(x)$ is "$x$ is odd" with domain the set of natural numbers.

Comment: 1. "may I consider the symbol ⊨ as if it was →? " Yes.  2. "m(f)={0,if f=p or;1,if f=q}" Your proof looks fine, and doesn't require such a function specification; one correct way to write it is "(m(f)=0 if f=p) and (m(f)=1 if f=q)"; what makes your version incorrect is the closing brace making it look like you're specifying the function as a set, and the "or" instead of "and".